# How to crop the image using the tapped points(like polygonal lasso in photoshop)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage

How can I crop the image using the tapping many points on the iPhone? See the image clear for you(Red points are tapping points). Like polygonal lasso in photoshop action.

I have no idea about this feature.

Please give some idea, suggestions, sample source code, pdf, etc...Whatever I want some aware of this functionality. Now I am blind for this task.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: You should have a look at UIBezier used in conjunction with CGPath that you create from your points. I've never used these APIs but I would begin there

Comment: Thanks Geraud.ch...If you have any other idea please post me.

Comment: @Mani did you find solution for this?